# Use subarray data from json to create rows of associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array, remap

I want to map my JSON response to specific array construction.

Here is my JSON data in short:

```
"code": 200,
"unit": null,
"data": [
    {
        "2022-11-16": 185.6159202
    },
    {
        "2022-11-17": 204.31997631
    },...
]
```

I need help to map this data to have array structure just like look array below:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array(
        [date] => 2018-01-03
        [value] => 0.0002444
    )
[1] => Array(
        [date] => 2018-01-04
        [value] => 0.0171476
    )
)
```

My code in PHP:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
$arr = $decoded['data'];
```

After that, the structure of the array looks like this, which is not quite what I expect:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [2018-01-03] => 0.0002444 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [2018-01-04] => 0.0171476 )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `array_keys()` and `array_values()` is not an ideal/optimal approach because this generates unnecessary depth while accessing the data.  See how `[0]` has to be written after each call?  It is not best practice to create a temporary array if you are only going to access the first item from it.  Just use `key()` and `current()` (or `reset()`).

Functional-style programming with `array_map()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1fn19))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($item) => ['date' => key($item), 'value' => current($item)],
        json_decode($json, true)['data']
    )
);
```

---

Classic foreach(): ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Mi16M))

```
$result = [];
foreach (json_decode($json, true)['data'] as $item) {
    $result[] = ['date' => key($item), 'value' => current($item)];
}
var_export($result);
```

Or with fewer iterated function calls: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0HQ3D))

```
$result = [];
foreach (json_decode($json, true)['data'] as $item) {
    $key = key($item);
    $result[] = ['date' => $key, 'value' => $item[$key]];
}
var_export($result);
```

Or with `compact()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8Ptld))

```
$result = [];
foreach (json_decode($json, true)['data'] as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $date => $value) {
        $result[] = compact(['date', 'value']);
    }
}
var_export($result);
```