# Convert flat, associative array into indexed 2d array with associative rows

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, mapping

I have an array like this

```
[
    123456 => 'John Doe'
    654321 => 'Doe John'
]
```

I want to change the array key (123456 and 654321) into an index (0,1,2,3,....,n) and save it into value, the expected result looks like this

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'code' => 123456.
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'Doe John',
        'code' => 654321.
    ),
)
```

this is the code i have tried, i have only gotten so far

```
$thearray= array_map(function ($value, $key) {
                return $key;
            }, $thearray, array_keys($thearray));
```

Comment: Somewhat related: [Use subarray data from json to create rows of associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74505955/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a foreach loop, define the keys and values using the keyname that you wish to see in the resultant rows, Then call `compact()` within the loops body before pushing the new row's data into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/S2R3X))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($thearray as $code => $name) {
    $result[] = compact(['name', 'code']);
}
var_export($result);
```

---

Your functional-style programming can be fixed up like this:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bGbBO))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($name, $code) => compact(['name', 'code']),
        $thearray,
        array_keys($thearray)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the foreach

```
$pemeriksa = [
    123456 => 'John Doe',
    654321 => 'Doe John'
];

$newArray = [];
foreach ($pemeriksa as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[] = ["name" => $value , "code" => $key];
}
print_r($newArray);
```